# Only run a macro if there is an email open

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script to process emails. User's can kick this script off by using a form.

I want them to only be able to use the form if they have an email open and in focus. So how can I check that the `CurrentItem` in:

```
objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

Is an email and is not another open window?

Answer (score 0):

To work with mail item that is open and has focus, use ActiveInspector method

Example blew to print subject if Item is `Mailitem`

```
Option Explicit
Sub Item_Info()
    Dim Active_Item As Object

    Set Active_Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    If TypeOf Active_Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Active_Item.Subject
    End If

End Sub
```